# how do I print dictionary keys with multiple values

Tags: python-3.x

I got into trouble while trying to print out a dictionary with its keys and values in pairs.

the dictionary has multiple keys and random amount multiple values assigned to some random key.

I am using python 3.4

I did some google around, but my results are quite different than what I was expecting.

my code is:

```
data = {'HAWAII': ['2006/10/19 2.5', '2006/10/20 3.1'],
    'MISSOURI': ['2006/10/18 3.4'],
    'INDONESIA': ['2006/10/20 4.9'],
    'PANAMA': ['2006/10/18 5.0'],
    'MEXICO': ['2006/10/20 2.8', '2006/10/18 3.3'], 
    'ALASKA': ['2006/10/19 2.8', '2006/10/18 2.6', '2006/10/18 2.7', '2006/10/18 2.7', '2006/10/18 2.8'],
    'VANUATU': ['2006/10/18 6.2']}

for k,v in data.items():
    print(str(k)+":"+str(v))
```

I have tried something else like:

```
for key in data:
    strA = key + ": "

  for data in value:
        strB = ''.join(data)
print("["+strA + "["+strB+"]"+"]"+"\n")
```

The expected result:

```
[ALASKA, [2006/10/19, 2.8], [2006/10/18, 2.6], [2006/10/18, 2.7], 
[2006/10/18, 2.7], [2006/10/18, 2.8]]

[MEXICO, [2006/10/20, 2.8], [2006/10/18, 3.3]]
```

kind of print them out by keys and different kv pairs in separate lines

Comment: Please edit your question so that 1. the code is indented correctly 2. the code is working (In your first example you have k vs. key, in your second example you use data twice with different meanings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print it like below:

```
for k, v in data.items():
    print('[{key}, {values}]'.format(key=k, values=', '.join('[{}]'.format(', '.join(x.split())) for x in v)))
```

The output comes out to be:

```
[MEXICO, [2006/10/20, 2.8], [2006/10/18, 3.3]]
[HAWAII, [2006/10/19, 2.5], [2006/10/20, 3.1]]
[MISSOURI, [2006/10/18, 3.4]]
[PANAMA, [2006/10/18, 5.0]]
[VANUATU, [2006/10/18, 6.2]]
[ALASKA, [2006/10/19, 2.8], [2006/10/18, 2.6], [2006/10/18, 2.7], [2006/10/18, 2.7], [2006/10/18, 2.8]]
[INDONESIA, [2006/10/20, 4.9]]
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. but I really need the output to be the exact format as i was expecting> its for an assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not really expecting my question will be answered in seconds. You are awesome.